# Update package installed list view with package update

Tags: package, list-view

I have some list views in my package, which I let our customers install.

Time passed, our requirements changed, I need to add a filter to those list views. So I updated them and **incorrectly guessed** it will update customer instances of those list views that were installed with the original package.

How to update that, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to have your clients fix it on their end. See the [ISVForce Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf) on pages 23-25 about what components can be upgraded by a version upgrade. List views cannot be upgraded, and can be deleted by a subscriber.